# Set blur on DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add blur to few DIVs, so I add this to the CSS:

```
.div{
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
    -moz-filter: blur(15px);
    -o-filter: blur(15px);
    -ms-filter: blur(15px);
    filter: blur(15px);
}
```

The problem is that when I'm scrolling the window, it scrolling with lags. This is not the only problem - this code isn't working on all browsers if I'm not mistaking. So how can I add a blur to a DIV?

Comment: Can you post more relevant code please and possibly even a Fiddle?

Comment: Filters are going to be somewhat processor intensive and are not universally supported. If you want to use a filter like this, you just have to accept that.

Comment: Instead of using processor expensive filters, you could consider bluring the image in photoshop or similar and using it as background...

Comment: @aleation took the words out of my mouth

Comment: @aleation The thing is that I want that when you click on image, like in facebook, you'll se her in big, but in facebook the background becomes darker, and I want it to become blurer. This page is long so I can't know where the screen is while he watching the popup images, and the page is responsive by the screen size - so it is another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cross-browser solution in pure CSS for this.
**Even in CSS3.**

You can still use **Blur.js** library (http://blurjs.com/),
it's crossbrowser but you need import javascript to your page.
(not be problem because blur is mostly just fancy effect).

Also this is nice DEMO (http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemBlur/)
with description what is going on (http://bit.ly/1aOE8uM) ..

Can helps you.

Comment: It seems great, but it doesn't work. I wrote in the JS file `$('#background').blurjs({source: 'body',radius: 10});` (#background) is an empty div with `position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:10;`, and it doesn't making blur on anything. I changes in the JS file form `#background` to `body` and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the link below, CSS filters are not that well supported. That's why it's not working in every browser.

http://caniuse.com/css-filters

As for the lag, you should post an example, because this should't have anything to do with the lag.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger the blur, the more memory-intensive it will be for the browser to render ([see here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/#toc-performance)).

To get any filter to work in Firefox, you'll need to define it in SVG (e.g. [for blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#blur%28%29)) and link to it using the [filter style's `url()` variant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#url%28%29). This approach should also work for versions of IE greater than 9.

Older IE has its own [equivalent `filter` style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms532979%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can use. If all else fails, you can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect support for the `filter` style and make the appropriate fallback adjustments (would need to add non-core detects for `css-filters` and `svg-filters`).